# selecting element by partial string that was loaded cannot grab value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, spring-mvc

I am currently working on an application that already has an existing functionality of loading information that i need to parse together with ajax calls loading this information in.  I am having an issue selecting an element value on the loaded document in that it is not returning a value to me based on the dom element which it IS selecting (tested by highlighting) and it is the only element being selected.  The jQuery code snippet in question is :

```
        $('.viewComponent').each(function(){
        //run ajax call to get the components
        var foodId = $(this).nextAll('input[name$=".code"]').val();
        $('#createComponentDialog').load('getComoponent.do', "foodID=" + foodId);
        calories = $('#createComponentDialog :input[name*="Calories"]').val();
    });
```

So as you can see for each component im loading the query and then trying to select a single field that is populated by the query to enter into another area later after doing some math however the val is returning as: ""  The dom element that its selecting in one instance of this is inside the id tag area but as loaded:

```
<li><label for="nutrients['Calories'].quantity">Calories</label><input id="nutrients'Calories'.quantity" name="nutrients['Calories'].quantity" class="text number" type="text" value="31.0" disabled="disabled"> kcal</li>
```

I included the label so if that would be an issue I am not sure, i have also run length debug and it is still not returning anything but a length of 1 so there is only one of these addressed inputs in the document that i can find with the jquery tags so im not dual selecting something.
This is fully running on a spring mvc stack so thats why there are some funky names going on.

EDIT: I found the problem with my script wasnt just there now i have a new issue and with it, a bit more of a snippet this time, maybe some sense can be had:

```
$('input.nutritionFacts').live('click', function(e){
    var servings = $('#servings').val();
    var calories = 0;
    var servSize = 0;
    $('.weight').each(function(){
        servSize += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $('#servSize').html(servSize);
    $('#servCont').html(servings);
    //for each component
    $('.viewComponent').each(function(){
        //run ajax call to get the components
        var foodId = $(this).nextAll('input[name$=".code"]').val();
        var weight = $(this).nextAll('.weight').val();
        $('#createComponentDialog').load('getComponent.do', "foodId=" + foodId, function(){
        console.log("loaded" + foodId + "successfully");
    });
        calories += parseFloat($("input[name*='Calories']").val());
    });
    $('#calories').html(calories);
    //run against weight from get components result
    //sum into form frame for nutritionfacts
    $('#nutritionFacts').dialog();
    console.log("loaded nutrients");
});
```

This is my current script, after doing many many tests, breakpoints for some reason were pausing and causing issues however it does populate data to the popup im creating properly now!
I as you can see am running a log and its ALWAYS firing line for "loaded nutrients" in my log FIRST Why would it do that?

Comment: Attribute "for" should contain a list of IDs, as far as i know.

Comment: And where are you reading calories that it is displaying nothing? Right after the line? Or is this the classic treating Async as Synch issue.

Comment: ive tried this selector with and without the id and it was still returning a .length value of 1 and where im reading the value is with chrome debug as its supposed to enter it into another dom element area and watching the variables being passed around with the variable inspector

Comment: What does `console.log($('#createComponentDialog :input[name*="Calories"]'));` return? A collection of one? Add the `.val()` to it, does it get the right value?

Comment: it returns nothing, i even tried the selector as      $('input[name*="Calories"]')     and its still returning as a no console response

Comment: I have been looking over this for a while now, the page is built in a few seperate form areas, it should still select the selector even if its in a seperate form area yes? If thats something im missing... It is populating into a jquery dialog box area that im not popping up.